# Help, weird "hard edged" appear on model

Tags: modeling

Hard edges appear randomly on my model. The edges was not crease, and the normal was not flipped. It even remained after I performed smooth vertices. It only disappear/hide if I use subdivide modifier. I prefer not to use it to maintain a low poly count

Furthermore, it only appear on this particular part(the image shown is the only place it appear on the entire model.)

The following is the provided blend file
[image]

Any idea how to solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've enabled *Auto Smooth*, it will sharpen all the angles that are over the chosen value, here 30°, so disable it or choose another value?

[image]

Comment: @moonbots thank you, it works, strange it only affect a part of model. Usually this problem affect  the entire model.